# CakePHP authorization plugin like CanCan for Rails

Tags: cakephp, authorization, cancan

I love approach used in [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) and I want to use something like this in my Cake apps. Does anyone know where to find such thing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it all in one file see [INI based ACL](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1244/Defining-Permissions-Cake-s-INI-based-ACL).

If that's not what you want it's still easy to do by extending the Auth Component in 1.3 or write an Auth/Authorize adapter in 2.0 with your custom logic, its simple.

Comment: Thank you but.. I think that's totally not what I want (at least how I get it).
[Here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) is what I wanted and [here](https://github.com/ok32/abilities) is what I wrote :D. I needed something that allows me to combine action level and row level authorization. What do you think?